# Is GenericItem default parent of each Item in Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have just started reading Hybris and read somewhere that GenricItem is by default parent of each item in Hybris. But on hybris wiki I found type hierarchy diagram which is [image]

Above diagram clearly denotes that parent Item is either object or ExtensibleItem, then why GenericItem is considered default parent Item of each item type.

Comment: I don't actually know hybris but _parent_ type sounds more like composition while _super_ type (what the diagram refers to) refers to inheritance. If that's the case here you probably can say that a `GenericItem` can _contain_ instances of the other types while `Order` _is a_ `ExtensibleItem` and `Category` _is a_ `GenericItem` (and a `ExtensibleItem`). The other thing that could apply here is the definition of "item": in the context of what you read they might actually only refer to subclasses of `GenericItem`.

Answer (score 1):

That diagram is not correct. Where did you find it exactly?

Comment: I found it on [wiki Hybris] (https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=release5&title=Type+System+Documentation)

Comment: Hmm 8 years old. But frankly i think it was wrong when it was created.

Comment: So should I consider GenericItem is default parent of each item. In that case what should i say about ExtensibleItem?

Comment: Why do you need to say anything? What did it ever say about you?

Comment: I was just trying to be clear about basic concepts of Hybris. Since I am a newbie so I am confused about its Type Structure. I will appreciate if you provide any link or book through which i can clear my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

GenericItem type is mother of all the type. Whether you have write or not, Hybris will implicitly extend this class.

```
<itemtype code="LocalizableItem"
              extends="ExtensibleItem"
              jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.c2l.LocalizableItem"
              deployment="de.hybris.platform.persistence.c2l.LocalizableItem"
              autocreate="true"
              generate="false" abstract="true">
    </itemtype>

    <itemtype code="GenericItem"
              extends="LocalizableItem"
              jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.GenericItem"
              deployment="de.hybris.platform.persistence.GenericItem"
              autocreate="true"
              generate="false">
    </itemtype>
```

Comment: hey Shreshtt you said GenericItem is mother of all the type but at the same time in your xml code GenericItem extends LocalizableItem which means LOcalizableItem is parent to GenericItem. Please explain

Answer (score 0):

After some research I concluded :-

1. If you do not extend any type, the default is GenericItem.
2. About the deployment property is the same. The topmost deployment is GenericItem, which is therefore the default deployment. This means if a type has no explicit specification of deployment, that type's instances are deployed in the same table as GenericItem.
3. The fig in question because of which i was confused is just an example which is subject to change(according to hybris experts).